# Laravel 8 shared host queue:work The Process class relies on proc_open

Tags: php, laravel, cron, queue, jobs

I'm trying to run the application jobs on a shared host in the scheduler function using:

```
$schedule->command('queue:restart')->everyFiveMinutes();
$schedule->command('queue:work')->everyMinute();
```

but I get this error:

```
production.ERROR: The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation.
```

I have already published the flare.php and did set collect_git_information to false
(I also re-cached the application) but still get this error. not sure if enabling proc_open is a good idea...

Comment: If you want to use the queue that's a requirement. Whether or not that's a good or bad idea depends on a lot of factors. Since this is shared hosting you might not have the option to begin with.

Comment: @apokryfos Oh, thank you so there is no workaround for this?